# Increase Label value by 1 when selecting a specific item from a Combobox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, combobox, label

I have a Form (Form1) where the ComboBox is located, and another form (Form2) where the label is located.

All I want to do is increase that label number when selecting a specific item from the ComboBox and clicking a button.

**The code from Form2:**

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public static int counter;

private void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if (combobox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Item1")
                        {
                            counter = Int32.Parse(Form2.labelincrease);
                            counter++;
                            Form2.labelincrease = counter.ToString();

                        } 
 }
}
```

**The code from Form 1:**

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 public static string labelincrease;
}

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    labelincrease = lblIncrease.Text.ToString()
    }
```

I am getting a lot of errors and I am trying a lot of methods but can't get there, I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You can use some kind of observer or mediator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

Instantiated `Form2 f2 = new Form2();`

`labelincrease = f2.lblIncrease.Text.ToString();`